# How to get the list of functions/UDFs within a loaded Addin

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel+VBA, how can I list the functions contained within an addin ?

Comment: Where do you want to list them?  What do you want to do with this list?

Comment: I will create a dialog with all the functions, and which addin they belong to

Comment: I can think of two ways of doing this.  The (in my opinion) safer method would be to have the add-in generate that list when it is loaded, using the workbook_addinInstall or workbook_open method (or both) to trigger the macro to do this.  A less safe method would require changing the Trust center settings so as to `Trust Access to the VBA project object model`, and then use the Microsoft Visual Basic For Applications Extensibility library to look at the entry directly.  But this can open you up to certain viruses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I ended up using `Application.RegisteredFunctions`. This works only for UDFs registered via addins though.